# "globbing" a file getting only those named numericlly?

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I would like to use the php function glob() to get those file which follow this pattern:

```
[arbitrary-text-code]-[any number].jpg
```

I can seem to find the way to do this.. also, is there another way to go about it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the ranges for `[any number]` arbitrary? If yes, I think your best option is [`preg_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php):

```
$text = '.+';
$number = '\d+';
$regex = $text . '-' . $number . '[.]jpg$';

$result = preg_filter('~' . $regex . '~i', '$0', glob('/your/path/*.jpg');
```

If, however, `[any number]` has a simple, small range (like `[0-9]`) `GLOB_BRACE` is your friend:

```
$result = glob('/your/path/*-{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.jpg', GLOB_BRACE);
```

---

**PS: I haven't tested the following and I'm not sure if it works but it's worth a shot.**

---

If your `[any number]` is between, lets say, `0` and `99`, this *might* work:

```
$result = glob('/your/path/*-{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.jpg', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Similarly, for `0` to `999`:

```
$result = glob('/your/path/*-{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.jpg', GLOB_BRACE);
```

You get the idea. The trick here is the empty option on the latter braces - let me know how it goes.

---

> **`GLOB_BRACE`** - Expands {a,b,c} to
>   match 'a', 'b', or 'c'.

Comment: THanks for the detailed response! It has helped me alot!

Comment: @Jeff: No problem! Which approach did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to `glob` a repeated pattern like *any number one or more times* so at the least youd have to glob something like `'*-*[0123456789].jpg'` and then `preg_grep` or something on the array it returns.

I have in the past pulled [`sfFinder`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/util/sfFinder.class.php) out of Symfony (usage [doc here](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/finder) - its outdated but the API hasnt change much) to do things like this so i wouldnt have to code my own solution :-) I assume there is probably something similar in PEAR or Zend Framework though if youre already using one of those.

Comment: Its made my work much easier in many projects, symfony and otherwise :-)